# Tor ip address blacklisted. Can anyone help?

Tags: ip-address

I've been using tor on my phone and now websites tell me my my ip address has been blacklisted and I am blocked from most sites. Anyone know how this can be fixed please?

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely not much you can really do.

**What you can try:**

- Switch exit relay until you find one that isn't blocked (might not be possible if the site updates it's blacklist frequently)

Except for that one option I don't think there is a way to bypass this.
Some sites unfortunately just block all Tor exit addresses.

Comment: I wish there was a list of Tor exit nodes who are not publicly known.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it would be useful. But there are some good reasons that there is a list available. See: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#HideExits